# weird behaviour ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller (AddCommentViewController) that can save comments offline and edit comments when saved offline.

When I load the AddCommentViewController in the view where I want to add a new comment and save it offline, there is no problem:

```
AddCommentViewController *addView = [AddCommentViewController new];

[addView setTitle:@"New Comment"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addView];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

[delegate.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[delegate dismissPopOver:self animated:YES];
[navController release];
[addView release];
```

No problem here, the view is animated nicely from the bottom. And when dismissed it is animated nicely to the bottom.

But now the problem.

In an other view I can see a list of all the comments saved offline. when I load the AddCommentViewController here something weird happens.

When I try to present the view modal it is animated from the left, stops at a weird location (not centred but a but to the buttom-right). and when I dismiss it, the view is animated back to the left side and my other view is orientated to portrait.
I can't seem to find the problem and the code is almost identical:

```
Comment *comment = [allComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

AddCommentViewController *addView = [[AddCommentViewController alloc] initWithId:comment.identifier];

[addView setTitle:@"Change comment"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addView];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor P4aPurple];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[navController release];
[addView release];
```

I tried to force the view at a specific orientation with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

but I get this error:

```
The view controller <UISplitViewController: 0x1843d0> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.
```

If I hold the device in portrait when I load an offline commend its working correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED, it turns out that the view has to be presented modal in the split view controller and not in the detail view controller of the split view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force Portrait orientation, try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;
    else return NO;
}
```